# cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit

Tags: solidity, contract-development, testnets, testing, ethers.js

I have an ERC721 contract on rinkeby and need to test the mint function, but sometimes I receive the fallowing error:

`Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit ... code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT`

This is my code:

```
const tx2 = await nft.connect(alice).mintPublicSale(1, {value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.04")});
await tx2.wait();
```

My wallet is already funded.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/70291328/1031297

Answer (score 4):

I got this error because I was using the wrong contract address. I was using the contract's mainnet address instead of it's Ropsten address. Make sure you have the right addresses for the network you're working with.

Answer (score 4):

In your hardhat.config.js add the following two params in your test network block

```
   gas: 2100000,
   gasPrice: 8000000000,
```

Answer (score 2):

in the function your calling add {gasLimit: 5000000} to the parameter

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar problem, there was a bug in my code, which caused the following error.

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit
```

This error is because the transaction was not complete and the contract (or the function called) failed.

Fixing the bug in my contract and re-deploying helped me get rid of this error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What was your bug? I can't find any bug, and when I'm using remix it works.

Comment: My bug was something trivial. I had similar looking functions with changed variables, and while doing so, I forgot to rename a variable and that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to check and change the network you account is connected to on the metamask. I was one of the standard testnet like ropsten and rinkeby instead of **localhost** where my contract was deployed to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the solution was to go to https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby and top up, it linked my MetaMask account in the process and I didn't have to change the code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, then checked my metamask for the balance, and found out my wallet was hacked and someone drained my test funds

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.

I solved it in this way.

1. Create a new directory totally empty: /blabla/createsmartaccount_dir.
2. Create these 2 files inside it.

/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/index.js

/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/package.json

3. Run the commands

npm install

node ./index.js

```
#/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/index.js

const { ethers } = require( 'ethers')
const { EthersAdapter } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const Safe = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const { SafeFactory } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const { SafeAccountConfig } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const { ContractNetworksConfig } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')

const execute = async () => {
    const RPC_URL='https://rpc2.sepolia.org'
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL)
    
    
    
    // Initialize signers
    //metamask wallet and privatekey
    //0x967c1CF5d91f3738c969c76EB4bDddA6da4183c1
    const signerWallet = 
new ethers.Wallet("ca46xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", provider)

    const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({ethers, signerOrProvider: signerWallet})
    
    const chainId = await ethAdapter.getChainId()
    console.log(`ChainId: ${chainId}`)

    
  
    
    const safeVersion = '1.3.0'
    const isL1SafeMasterCopy = false
    const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter: ethAdapter })



    const safeAccountConfig = {
        threshold: 1, // Have to be >= 1 && <= totalOwners
        owners: ["0x967xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
        eth_estimateGas:30000,
    }
    console.log("Start Deploying Safe");



    
    
    //This Safe is tied to owner 1 because the factory was initialized with an 
    //adapter that had owner 1 as the signer. 
  
    const safeSdkOwner1 = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig })

    const safeAddress = safeSdkOwner1.getAddress()

    console.log(`Safe deployed at: ${safeAddress}`)  
}
execute();
```

```
#/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/package.json

{
  "dependencies": {
    "@safe-global/api-kit": "^1.0.1",
    "@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^0.1.1",
    "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "^1.10.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ethers": "5.7.2"
  }
}
```

[Periodic failure when attempting to create gnosis safe via @safe-global/protocol-kit SDK](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150579/periodic-failure-when-attempting-to-create-gnosis-safe-via-safe-global-protocol/150771#150771)