# Periodic failure when attempting to create gnosis safe via @safe-global/protocol-kit SDK

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have been using this code to create Gnosis safe programmatically:

```
const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({ethers, signerOrProvider: signerWallet}); //3
const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter }); //4
const safeSdk: Safe = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig: { threshold: 2, owners: ['0x...', '0x...', '0x..'] }});
```

But today, in a few attempts to create Gnosis Safes on Goerli, I got this error:

```
cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted: Create2 call failed", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x12A244d6137dFE45B85F92185C524340D8CdD60f","to":"0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2","data":"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","accessList":null}, error={"code":-32603,"message":"execution reverted: Create2 call failed","data":{"originalError":{"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013437265617465322063616c6c206661696c656400000000000000000000000000","message":"execution reverted: Create2 call failed"}},"docUrl":"https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/wallet-sdk/docs/errors?version=3.7.0&code=-32603&method=eth_estimateGas&message=execution+reverted%3A+Create2+call+failed"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
```

I double checked to make sure there is fund in my wallet. Any pointer toward how I may solve/debug this issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.

I solved it in this way.

1. Create a new directory totally empty: /blabla/createsmartaccount_dir.
2. Create these 2 files inside it.

/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/index.js

/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/package.json

3. Run the commands

npm install

node ./index.js

```
#/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/index.js

const { ethers } = require( 'ethers')
const { EthersAdapter } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const Safe = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const { SafeFactory } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const { SafeAccountConfig } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')
const { ContractNetworksConfig } = require(  '@safe-global/protocol-kit')

const execute = async () => {
    const RPC_URL='https://rpc2.sepolia.org'
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL)
    
    
    
    // Initialize signers
    //metamask wallet and privatekey
    //0x967c1CF5d91f3738c969c76EB4bDddA6da4183c1
    const signerWallet = 
new ethers.Wallet("ca46xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", provider)

    const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({ethers, signerOrProvider: signerWallet})
    
    const chainId = await ethAdapter.getChainId()
    console.log(`ChainId: ${chainId}`)

    
  
    
    const safeVersion = '1.3.0'
    const isL1SafeMasterCopy = false
    const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter: ethAdapter })



    const safeAccountConfig = {
        threshold: 1, // Have to be >= 1 && <= totalOwners
        owners: ["0x967xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
        eth_estimateGas:30000,
    }
    console.log("Start Deploying Safe");



    
    
    //This Safe is tied to owner 1 because the factory was initialized with an 
    //adapter that had owner 1 as the signer. 
  
    const safeSdkOwner1 = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig })

    const safeAddress = safeSdkOwner1.getAddress()

    console.log(`Safe deployed at: ${safeAddress}`)  
}
execute();
```

```
#/blabla/createsmartaccount_dir/package.json

{
  "dependencies": {
    "@safe-global/api-kit": "^1.0.1",
    "@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^0.1.1",
    "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "^1.10.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ethers": "5.7.2"
  }
}
```