# Unable to deploySafe due to Unpredictable Gas Limit

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm trying out the [Quickstart for Protocol Kit](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/protocol-kit).

I was able to deploy a Safe successfully just one time. However, I encountered error when I tried to deploy another Safe right after, with the same exact code.

This is the error I got:

`Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit`

`reason: 'execution reverted: Create2 call failed', code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',`

Here is my [repo](https://github.com/0xNike/Safe-Protocol/blob/main/index.ts)

Comment: I have tried to specify the gasLimit using the `options: EthersTransactionOptions`. That gives me another error: `reason: transaction failed. code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION'`

Comment: Did you check other posts- https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150579/periodic-failure-when-attempting-to-create-gnosis-safe-via-safe-global-protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safes are deployed in a deterministic way. This means that everytime the method to deploy a Safe in the Safe Factory contract is called with the same configuration for the Safe account (owners, threshold, etc.), the same address will be generated. It makes sense that the second time you tried it returned this error, as the calculated address was already in use with the previous deployed Safe proxy contract. To avoid this collision use the `saltNonce` parameter. Using the timestamp, for instance, should solve this issue.

Comment: Oh you're such a blessing. That worked. Thanks!!